# How to set the query in a relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have this tables

usercontract

[image]

user

[image]

invite

[image]

Invite contain the invitations to participate in a contract and they are send by email. I want to use the email as id in order to get all the contracts a user as been invited to participate to.
And I need to do it as a relationship on my User model, so I can use the logged user email as filter.

This is the relationship I have defined but is using the id of the user to match with the foreing_key (usercontract) on the invite table. I don't understand very well why.

```
public function nonAcceptedContracts()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserContract::class, 'invite', 'email', 'usercontract');
}
```

I need it as a relationship because I want to call it on my repository, like this.

```
public function showRelated(User $user)
    {
        $parentUser = $user->parentUser;
        $usercontract = UserContract
            ::with(['topics', 'contracttax', 'contractproperty', 'persons', 'contractwarranty', 'contractencumbrance', 'users', 'contracts', 'tags'])
            ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user, $parentUser) {
                $user->loadMissing('nonAcceptedContracts');
                dd($user->nonAcceptedContracts);
                $query->where('id', $user->getAuthIdentifier());
                if ($parentUser) {
                    $query->orWhere('parent', $parentUser->id);
                }
                if ($user->siblingUsers()->count() > 0) { // get contracts of the sibling-users of the user
                    $query->orWhereIn('id', $user->siblingUsers()->pluck('id'));
                }
                if ($user->subUsers->count() > 0) { // get contracts of the users sub-users
                    $query->orWhereIn('id', $user->subUsers->pluck('id'));
                }
                return $query;
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    }
```

I guess my question is how to set a relationship in order to get the usercontracts for that user (the object) using his email as a key to get the usercontract id (usercontract) on the invite table.

```
SELECT * FROM `usercontract` WHERE usercontract.id IN (SELECT invite.id FROM invite WHERE `invite`.`email` = 'someemail@gmail.com')
```

Comment: $this->belongsToMany(UserContract::class, 'invite', 'email', 'usercontract'); This seems to be working. The sql sentence looks fine. Except for that "?" where it should be the email of the logged user.
"select * from `usercontract` inner join `invite` on `usercontract`.`id` = `invite`.`usercontract` where `invite`.`email` = ? and `usercontract`.`deleted_at` is null"

Answer (score 0):

```
public function nonAcceptedContracts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserContract::class, 'invite', 'email', 'usercontract', 'email')->where('status', 'pending');
}
```

That relationship uses my "invite" table as pivot using the "email" and "usercontract" has keys and filtering the results with the "email" of the "user" table.